# Laravel response 404 file not found

Tags: php, angular, laravel, dingo-api

I'm using Dingo/API and this is a transformer that returns me data

```
return [
            'id' => $site->id,
            'path' => asset($site->path),
            'siteLink' => $site->site_link,
            'features' => $features,
        ];
```

Generated link looks good, however when I try to access it from my Angular app it's said that

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://api.example.com/public/thumbnails/ySOSYhaCCRcH3t9agsco3ToUwoHxMZJ3r1PhEHlM.jpeg

Comment: are you sure the picture(ySOSYhaCCRcH3t9agsco3ToUwoHxMZJ3r1PhEHlM.jpeg) exist?

Comment: yes I am. I've checked it

Comment: if `api.example.com` is a Laravel app then the "public" directory is usually the root of the website. Maybe try sending 'path' without the public bit

Comment: it's a path generated by laravel itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The solution.

In `filesystems.php` local disk was specified as a default disk. According to docs `local` disk is supposed to be `invisible` for public and stored inside `storage/app`. Thus I was trying to save my file using `local` disk and accessing it with path `public/...`.

### Option #1

Change in `filesystems.php` default disk to `public` and use `Storage::url()` to get url to image.

### Option #2

Use `$file->store('path', 'public')` and `Storage::disk('public')->url('path')`

So that used disk is specified explicitly.

The given path will contain link close to `http://example.com/storage/path`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your image stored in public/public folder?
asset() helper generate a asset path from public folder. So, in your property $site->path you getting a path to your image like 'public/yourimage.jpeg'. Try to remove 'public' from your $site->path.